# How to express in Japanese "to mark" something?

Tags: word-usage

The background is the factory's production zone. There are lots of *boxes* with different filling. There are boxes with *finished products*, but also there are boxes with *NG-products* (defect products). Every box **has to be marked** with some coloured label, telling what kind of product is inside the box.

If I need **to mark** several boxes, could I express my sentence in Japanese using the verb "**表示する{ひょうじする}**" or there is some better way to express the process of marking by stickering colourful info-labels on the boxes?

Also, if I mark boxes *just by writing* info on them, not using a sticker, if I still can use the verb **表示する**?
Thank you so much in advance for your comments!

Comment: 「[印]{しるし}をつける」とかですかね・・・？

Comment: 印かな…　ちょうど「印」という言葉をこの場合に使えるかどうか確信はありません…

Answer (score 3):

By writing, using a sticker or even using a lamp, you can still use 表示する.

To me, 表示する puts emphasis on "a certain meaning is reported."

> あの LED は、使用中であることを表示している。 That LED shows that it is in use.
>
> これは会場の方向を表示する看板だ。 This sign shows the direction to the site.
>
> 手を振り払って拒絶の意思を表示する。 By shaking off her hand, I showed her I refused her.

As you see, their を-objects indicate what are reported.

Back to your question,
「すべての箱に、欠陥品かどうかを表示しなければならない。」sounds abstract to me.
You can make different types of holes or marks, you can write or you can put labels on them.

印をつける sounds more specific. It means "put some marks."

I would explain "marking by stickering colourful info-labels on the boxes" as
箱の上に色付きのラベルを貼ることで印をつける or something like that.